# Adding column in existing table without using migration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any method to adding column in existing table without using migration. I mean executing `php artisan migrate` and creating migration file through program/code in Laravel rather than CLI. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that on using Laravel framework?

Comment: Her @codervine i want it because i m doing GIS project. So after conversion of shapefile using POSTGIS we will get table which unaware to Laravel, it does not contain any migration. So i like to add column on that table using Laravel. Is there any way, to do that ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration files are only an easy way to create tables and other db actions, you still can use raw queries on Laravel anywhere by using DB::raw(...); check its documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) to proper use it.

You may also be able to write a Schema::table(,,,) anywhere on your code, it will return some a Schema object which you can execute some method to run the code on your apo runtime, if you are using some IDE just try to explore and see what will you have by typing Schema::table(...)->

Comment: Wow. I was aware of raw queries, but Scehma Builder is what i was searching for. It works me pretty well. Thank you so much @Thiago

Answer (score 0):

Try this add just column in your migration table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->string('name');// only add this line
    });
}
```

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Comment: Thanks. But i want to add without using migration. i got raw query option but still i m searching for best method.